# Linux ceases to respond to keyboard/mouse

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, mouse, suspend

Recently upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on desktop computer. Hardware from System76 (LeopardX), selected for Linux/Ubuntu compatibility. All is well except after about a day, system will not respond to keyboard or mouse. Can ssh in from another system. Can sudo reboot from another system. But can't control system from local keyboard/mouse. I thought it might have to do with suspend. But I configured power settings to never suspend and the only difference was that now I can see the screen (mouse doesn't affect cursor). Any advice would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Re-enable the [System76 PPA](https://launchpad.net/~system76-dev/+archive/ubuntu/stable) and reinstall `system76-driver` and, if applicable, `nvidia-graphics-drivers-375`.